# R: Splitting Data in Column by Ambiguous Values

Tags: r, datatable, data.table

Suppose we have this data:

```
Country                 Value
China Word1             1,427,647,786
India Word2             1,352,642,280
United States Word3     327,096,265
Indonesia WordsHere     267,670,543
Pakistan ThisIsAWord    212,228,286
Brazil Test Test        209,469,323
Nigeria Hello           195,874,683
Bangladesh Word5        161,376,708
Russia Words            145,734,038
Mexico This Word        126,190,788
```

I would like to separate the Country from the word next to it (e.g. Word1 ....) into two columns. Obviously I could just us a delimiter, e.g. space or comma. But it becomes problematic since some countries have spaces in them. And it sits within an application where I won't necessarily know which countries will be used. So I can't make a list of exceptions manually.

The closest I have gotten is using various "Fuzzy match" function which I have found online. However, they only seem to work 90% of the time. This unfortunately unacceptable in this use-case...

EDIT: Added spaces between some words to more accurately reflect the data at hand, following comment by @Limey.

Comment: In your test data, you have the country followed by just one word.  So why not just look for the *last* word and delete that?  if your real data has edge cases where you may have multi word countries and multi word garbage, or countries with no trailing word, then I think the only 100% reliable approach will be to have a look up list of countries.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks! However I did just have another look at the data and there are cases of multi-words (with spaces). I'll have a look at country look-ups.

Comment: @Limey, how would I go about using a lookup table to match it with the Country column above? Since they don't match 100%. That is the approach I already tried, meaning I have a lookup list, then I used one of those fuzzy match methods. They are not accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in OP's second comment:

```
# Test data
text <- c("China Word1", "India Word2", "United States Word3", "Indonesia WordsHere", 
          "Pakistan ThisIsAWord", "Brazil Test Test", "Nigeria Hello",
          "Bangladesh Word5", "Russia Words", "Mexico This Word")

countryList <- c("China", "India", "United States", "Indonesia", 
                 "Pakistan", "Brazil", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh", 
                 "Russia", "Mexico")

# Demo code
pattern <- paste0(countryList, collapse="|")
foundCountries <- stringi::stri_match_first(text, regex=pattern)
foundCountries
```

Giving

```
     [,1]           
 [1,] "China"        
 [2,] "India"        
 [3,] "United States"
 [4,] "Indonesia"    
 [5,] "Pakistan"     
 [6,] "Brazil"       
 [7,] "Nigeria"      
 [8,] "Bangladesh"   
 [9,] "Russia"       
[10,] "Mexico"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on `library(countrycode)`, which contains a large dictionary of country names in all sorts of variants; here I select English country names stored in `codelist$country.name.en`:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(countries = c("China Word1", "India Word2", "United States Word3", "Indonesia WordsHere", 
          "Pakistan ThisIsAWord", "Brazil Test Test", "Nigeria Hello",
          "Bangladesh Word5", "Russia Words", "Mexico This Word"))
```

Solution:

The solution works by defining all country names in `codelist$country.name.en` as patterns connected by the alternation marker `|`and remembering each in the backreference `\\1`, from where they can replace the verbose country names *iff* they match:

```
library(countrycode)

df$country_clean <- gsub(paste0(".*\\b(", paste(codelist$country.name.en, collapse="|"),")\\b.*"), 
                     "\\1", df$countries, perl = T )
```

Result:

```
df
              countries country_clean
1           China Word1         China
2           India Word2         India
3   United States Word3 United States
4   Indonesia WordsHere     Indonesia
5  Pakistan ThisIsAWord      Pakistan
6      Brazil Test Test        Brazil
7         Nigeria Hello       Nigeria
8      Bangladesh Word5    Bangladesh
9          Russia Words        Russia
10     Mexico This Word        Mexico
```

Comment: That's a good resource, @Chris.  I wasn't aware of it.  Thanks for pointing it out.